# Discriminator Property

Tags: c#, .net, linq

[Working through this step by step guide.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384467.aspx)

I am trying to create the inheritance between BirthAppointment / tblAppointment. However I need the Discriminator Property to be set to appCatId.

The appCatId is held within tblAppointmentType. How can I access this.

[alt text http://www.zero7web.com/RegBook-linq.jpg](http://www.zero7web.com/RegBook-linq.jpg)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Clare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I understanding correctly that you want `BirthAppointment` to inherit from `tblAppointment`? If this is the case, discrimnator property is a field in the database table that used to distinguish records that represent `tblAppointment` objects from `BirthAppointment` objects. As such, you can't use `appCatId` since it lives in another table (`tblAppointmentType`).

Comment: a new appointment type is not required for each appTypeID, just the main categories (appCatID) as the properties will be the same for all the types of the same category. I'm sure someone must of come across this before? 

Thanks

PS im working on the same problem with Clare

Comment: Those are domain issues. I am merely explaining to you that with your current schema you can not do what you are trying to do. The discriminating property must be a property in the base of your inheritance hierarchy. So you need to find a property that distinguishes objects of type tblAppointment from those of type BirthAppointment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Visual Studio's Properties window.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531247.aspx

Comment: The only options I can access are within the tblAppointment. I thought I would be able to access it by doing something like:

tblAppointment.tblAppointmentType.appCatID

within the Discriminator Property tab.